# Make a custom picture extension behave like an existing one on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, images, file-association, content-type-association

OK, so I understand that this may be achievable by combining a number of answers from other questions, but the exact recipe has been eluding me and I wonder if there isn't an actual 'correct' way of doing it (maybe via VBScript or similar).

I would like to rename some TIFF files to a different extension, but I'd like them to behave just like TIFF files do on Windows - thumbnails, picture viewer, associations. I've tried dabbling with the shellex in the registry (for some reason my registry doesn't have shellex for common types, yet everything seems to work), making a duplicate of the tiff root class, but neither of those worked. I may have done it wrong. I'm also unsure of what's needed after such changes (the description of the file type in Explorer seems to change right away).

So I thought of asking you before I damage something. Maybe this can be useful to someone else besides me!

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what extension you'd like to rename them to, but this is easily done.

1. Fire up registry editor and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Classes\.tif`
2. With the .tif key highlighted, click File -> Export and export the key to a .reg file.
3. Open the .reg file in Notepad and replace the .tif in key names with whatever extension you want.
4. Import the .reg file back into the registry.

**NOTE** -- Don't use an extension that is already being used by something else or you'll destroy the file association for that extension.

Comment: Could you please post your own export of the .tif class?